# How to send special characters like "++" and "#" in a request?

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, request, response

I am trying to make an request to an ASP .NET CORE API, from an Angular application using Typescript.

When i send the request it searches in an SQL database if there is any row with that value.

The problem is when i try to send a request where `Syntax = "C++"` or `"C#"` it only send this:

```
/FindBySyntax?Syntax=C
```

instead of `/FindBySyntax?Syntax=C#` or `/File/FindBySyntax?Syntax=C++`

Example: If i try to send  "Javascript" its work and it returns me all the rows where `Syntax="Javascript"`.

I want to know if there is a way to send special characters like "++" and "#" in the request and how can i do it?

```js
selectSyntax(file: FileModel){
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, file);
    return this.http.get(this.service.BaseURL + '/File/FindBySyntax?Syntax=' + this.service.formData.Syntax)
    .toPromise()
            .then(res => this.service.list = res as FileModel[]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encode all special characters using [Encode URI component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
const encodedSyntax = encodeURIComponent(this.service.formData.Syntax);
return this.http.get(this.service.BaseURL + '/File/FindBySyntax?Syntax=' + encodedSyntax)
```

You may have to decode this on the server with the equivalent [Decode URI component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) in the language of choice

Answer (score 1):

The content of `this.service.formData.Syntax` should be converted with `encodeURIComponent()` JavaScript function.

Documentation about `encodeURIComponent()` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). About the decoding on ASP .NET Core side [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_).